# Is there any way to adding an attached property to a tabItem without using Style setter?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, attached-properties

I need to add attached property to my dynamic tabControl itemTab.
Right now i am doing

```
                <TabControl.Resources>

                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" 
                           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}" >
                        <Setter Property="aa:attachedClass.Property" Value="True">
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </TabControl.Resources>
```

It works but it has a problem while changing the style.

if i move the basedOn property, i ll get the default ItemTemplate.

If i try to add the attached property to the related dataTemplate it does not work (Check it usin Snoop)

Any suggestion please ?

Comment: can you post your attached property code?
you can make it target TabControl and handle searching TabItems in it. This way you will attach it to tabcontrol

Comment: @netaholic . There is no issue with the attached property code because i am using in a generic way (With many Controls).

Comment: I understand that. But if your tabcontrols children are generated by data template, then I believe the only way of assigning attached property in xaml is throught style, what doesn't suit you. Instead, you can modify your behaviour to target tabcontrol and to find tabcontrol items and apply the desired behaviour to them.

Comment: i get your point @netaholic. Doing that on the behaviour code is not convinient for me. Because there i am just getting the dataContext of the attaching Control and calling a method from my baseViewModel :)

Comment: it doesn't seem to me as correct use-case of behaviours. I assume you are doing MVVM. And you bind a collection of viewmodels, represented by YourControl, to a tabControl. Why wouldn't you address this collection in code of a viewmodel, which you have tab control in?

Comment: it's more than a viewModel on One screen (Existing code maan :D );
 I use behaviour here to change to target the ViewModel method when i press a key on my keyboard and the do what is supposed to be done throu the targeted ViewModel

Comment: don't understand your requirement, there are some ways to set a property like this: ***directly in code, directly on the element, via Style setter, via Trigger setter, via Binding, via animation***. So which way do you want it to be set (if not via Style setter)?

Comment: @netaholic. I have already resolevd it by applying my attached property and i made "Focusable" property = True (StackPanel inside the DataTemplate)